# How to find the packet lost in veins omnet++

Tags: omnet++, veins

In veins example of omnetpp I changed the value of alpha and tried to analyse the total lost packet, but for the different values of alpha.

The packet lost remains zero even the SNIR lost packets remains zero. Can any one help me with that?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have a link to the example code, or can you post your code?

Comment: i havent changed the code of the example just changed the alpha value of the pathloss model in veins example but in results the total lost packets remains zero i am not sure why it is happening.

Comment: You might have changed the wrong alpha value, or you might have set it to a value that is too similar

Comment: i changed the alpha value in config.xml file in <AnalogueModels>
<AnalogueModel type="SimplePathlossModel">
<parameter name="alpha" type="double" value="4.0"/> and also in the omnetpp.ini and in the phylayer80211p.cc files but still the totalpacketlost are zero for all nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried running the example scenario that comes with Veins 4a2. Other than you, I am seeing lost packets (0 for many nodes, but up to 14 for some nodes). Something might be wrong with the way you are collecting statistics.

[image: histogram of lost packets]

For Veins 3.0, statistics are very similar (though notably not exactly the same, due to changes in the radio model):

[image]

Comment: thank you for the answer, could it be because of the different version of veins i am using the veins 3.0 and even following the exact procedure i dont find the packet lost ?  i am recording the results using the simulation library, directly in c++ code . do you suggest that i should compute the results using the signal mechanism or declaring the statistics ?

Comment: I've amended my answer with statistics for Veins 3

Comment: thank you so much it is clear that change of version has no effect on it. actually the problem lies in the change of the maps i tried changing the erlangen with the map files( which is my own controverted osm map). i cant seem to find the packets lost in that. even i did not change any parameter other then the erlangen files i cant seemed to find any packet lost